# How to pass variables in CLinkPager?

Tags: yii, yii1.x

How to pass variables in CLinkPager for pagination in yii ?

`<?php    $this->widget('CLinkPager', array('pages' => $pages,))    ?>`

On using the above code, I cannot pass variables and an error message of undefined index is shown.How to solve this problem in CLinkPager ?

Comment: Can you describe what variables you want to pass? Are you trying to change CLinkPager properties or just passing data to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customization pagination url, you can use:

```
CPagination::createPageUrl()
```

This method is mainly called by pagers when creating URLs used to perform pagination. The default implementation is to call the controller's createUrl method with the page information. You may override this method if your URL scheme is not the same as the one supported by the controller's createUrl method.

OR if you need to add Only Params, you can add params to array like

```
CPaginationObj->params = array of parameters (name=>value) that should be used instead of GET when generating pagination URLs.
```